# Why doesn't firebase work? It doesn't make an account

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-authentication

```
//set up register function 

  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  // Initialize variables
  const auth = firebase.auth()
  const database = firebase.database()
  
  // Set up our register function
  function register () {
    // Get all our input fields
    email = document.getElementById('email').value
    password = document.getElementById('password').value
    full_name = document.getElementById('full_name').value
    favourite_song = document.getElementById('favourite_song').value
    milk_before_cereal = document.getElementById('milk_before_cereal').value
  
    // Validate input fields
    if (validate_email(email) == false || validate_password(password) == false) {
      alert('Email or Password is Outta Line!!')
      return
      // Don't continue running the code
    }
    if (validate_field(full_name) == false || validate_field(favourite_song) == false || validate_field(milk_before_cereal) == false) {
      alert('One or More Extra Fields is Outta Line!!')
      return
    }
   
    // Move on with Auth
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function() {
      // Declare user variable
      var user = auth.currentUser
  
      // Add this user to Firebase Database
      var database_ref = database.ref()
  
      // Create User data
      var user_data = {
        email : email,
        full_name : full_name,
        last_login : Date.now()
      }
  
      // Push to Firebase Database
      database_ref.child('users/' + user.uid).set(user_data)
  
      // DOne
      alert('User Created!!')
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // Firebase will use this to alert of its errors
      var error_code = error.code
      var error_message = error.message
  
      alert(error_message)
    })
  }
  
  // Set up our login function
  function login () {
    // Get all our input fields
    email = document.getElementById('email').value
    password = document.getElementById('password').value
  
    // Validate input fields
    if (validate_email(email) == false || validate_password(password) == false) {
      alert('Email or Password is Outta Line!!')
      return
      // Don't continue running the code
    }
  
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function() {
      // Declare user variable
      var user = auth.currentUser
  
      // Add this user to Firebase Database
      var database_ref = database.ref()
  
      // Create User data
      var user_data = {
        last_login : Date.now()
      }
  
      // Push to Firebase Database
      database_ref.child('users/' + user.uid).update(user_data)
  
      // DOne
      alert('User Logged In!!')
  
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // Firebase will use this to alert of its errors
      var error_code = error.code
      var error_message = error.message
  
      alert(error_message)
    })
  }
  
  
  
  
  // Validate Functions
  function validate_email(email) {
    expression = /^[^@]+@\w+(\.\w+)+\w$/
    if (expression.test(email) == true) {
      // Email is good
      return true
    } else {
      // Email is not good
      return false
    }
  }
  
  function validate_password(password) {
    // Firebase only accepts lengths greater than 6
    if (password < 6) {
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    }
  }
  
  function validate_field(field) {
    if (field == null) {
      return false
    }
  
    if (field.length <= 0) {
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    }
  }
```

and here's my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sign.css"
    <title>Log in</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Homepage</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="/aboutus">About us</a>
              <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div>Sussy baka
          <h1>Welcome</h1>
          <form action="/register">
              <label>Email</label>
              <input type="text" id="email">
              <label>Password</label>
              <input type="password" id="password">
              <div>
                <button onclick="Login()">Login</button>
                <button onclick="Register()">Register</button>
            
          </form>
      </div>
</body>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
         https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
         <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-auth.js"></script>
         <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

There are no errors that show up in vs code and even in dev console, there are no errors shown. FIrebase also doesn't show any errors. So I don't understand what the issue is... This is my first time using js for my school project so I'm not to particular about js. Ive been trying to fix this issue for the past couple weeks now and it still hasn't been fixed yet...

Answer (score 2):

With the following imports

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

you should see an error in the browser console. As a matter of fact you are mixing up the JS SDK version 9 with the version 8 one.

From the signature of the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` in your code we can see that you want to use the SDK version 8, so you should adapt the import as follows:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

*Note that you may upgrade to version [8.10.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_8100_-_august_19_2021)*

---

Then you have another error: your function is named `register()` but you call it as `Register()`.

---

All these errors should normally appear in the browser console and you should debug them one by one.

Comment: AHH ok thanks I'll fix it